# Compiled OpenSSL 1.1.1k but library shows older version

Tags: debian, openssl

I have compiled the latest version of `OpenSSL 1.1.1k` on Debian Buster.

```
./config
make
sudo make install
```

However when I check the version, I realise only the tool has been updated and not the underlying library. What am I missing please?

```
> openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019)
```

Comment: You probably have a system installed version of openssl. Without full path the shell will follow the folders of the PATH environment variable. The compiled version should be installed elsewhere. Probably in /usr/local/bin. Try to run the command with full path: /usr/local/bin/openssl version.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where the path for openssl is set? I checked `~/.bashrc`and can't see it. (see my answer below thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.  Prior to compilation I had `libssl-dev` installed, which collided with this. Despite `sudo apt remove libssl-dev` I couldn't get rid of it. Maybe a purge would have helped. I didn't try it.

I had to reinstall Debian but this time I didn't install `libssl-dev`.

```
sudo -E apt install software-properties-common build-essential make wget
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.1.1k/
./config
make
sudo make install
```

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019

sudo ldconfig
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021)
```

Then after reboot.

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
```

And I found a way to avoid reboot.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/ssl/bin:${PATH}"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: You need to update the library cache with `ldconfig` when you move shared libraries around, then you can avoid the reboot.

Comment: Thanks, that helped to update the library. But not the path to executable. But I found a way.

Comment: Executable locations are cached by each shell instance, the `hash` builtin command can be used to change this cache.